# OpenCV cv2.CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR

Tags: python, opencv

I tried to run the following in python:

```
import cv2
im_A = cv2.imread(path_A, cv2.CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR)
```

But there is an error message "module 'cv2' has no attribute 'CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR'. Why?

Comment: what do you want to achive in opencv2 you can just read by using cv2.imread(pathImage)

Answer (score 9):

I guess you are not using Python (or C++) flags in your syntax.
You must instead use the `IMREAD_COLOR` constant.

```
import cv2
im = cv2.imread('link_to_file', cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
```